# Do any birds have established "poke a predator's eyes out" behavior?

Tags: ornithology, ethology, behaviour

Is there a pattern/tactics of behavior in any birds species that consists of **attacking a predator's eyes with its beak**?

I'm looking for established tactics, not 1 or 2 anecdotal examples.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I arrived at the question when trying to answer http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/how-came-fawkes-know-how-to-disable-basilisk :)

Answer (score 3):

From this paper about [black-headed gulls](http://www.jstor.org.proxy.cc.uic.edu/stable/30039149?seq=7#page_scan_tab_contents) responding to a hedgehog:

> The gull might peck the intruder, or strike it with its feet. Pecks were
>   mostly directed at the hedgehog's head and might be delivered after a
>   horizontal approach with the wings partly lifted.

Although not directed at the eyes specifically, they observed the birds directing attacks to the predator's head.

There's another paper ([Ratner 1975](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-2835-3_8#page-1)) that also looks promising, but I'm on my home computer and can't access it right now

Comment: Any luck on the second paper? Thanks!

Comment: @DVK Sadly I don't have access to it at work either, sorry!